# How to auto-increment non-numeric ID in mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I want to auto-increment 'Project_ID' using mongo DB. I need to put 'Project_ID' value as 'demo_1', so using this value when I trying to auto-increment this value, it showing error: can not increment non numeric id.

```
public static Object getNextSequence(String Project_ID) throws Exception{
           // MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
            // Now connect to your databases
           // DB db = mongoClient.getDB("demo");
            DB db=ConnectToDB.getConnection();
              Properties prop = new Properties();
              InputStream input = null;
                input = Demo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
                prop.load(input);
                String col=prop.getProperty("COLLECTION_DEMO");
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("counters");
            BasicDBObject find = new BasicDBObject();
            find.put("_id", Project_ID);
            BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
            update.put("$inc", new BasicDBObject("seq", 1));
            DBObject obj =  collection.findAndModify(find, update);
            db.getMongo().close();
            return obj.get("seq");
        }
Please let me know what is the issue there or what is the possible way to achieve this. Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation of what you're trying to autoincrement does not match the code, never mind the error.   You're code is trying to autoincrement `seq`in a document keyed by Project_ID, in this case `demo_1`.
I ran your code although I got no errors, it is possible you don't have a "seed" record to findAndModify().   Try running this to create your seed:

```
db.counters.drop();
db.counters.insert({_id: "demo_1", seq: NumberInt("0")});
```

then run your code.
Also:  You are connecting and closing the connection with each call to `getNextSequence`.  That will be really slow.  I recommend you open the DB and capture the collection in `main()`and close it upon exit.